# Ceiling fan replacement motor amperage difference, is it a problem?

Tags: electrical, bathroom, electric-motor

I have a fan in my bathroom, but it appears to be dead. I took the fan apart, the "fan" is a motor piece which has a standard (US) two prong plug that you just plug into the fan outlet. The outlet works fine, I plugged a wall lamp into and it's ok.

I'm trying to get a replacement motor piece now, the unit has the following written on it:

```
Broan NuTone LLC
99080351
SP-61K20
120V/60Hz 0.9A
```

There are some other numbers on it that just look like serial numbers, I did a search for "SP-61K20", and there are some matching results. The power section is a little different though, they read:

```
120V/60Hz 1.2A
```

Is there amperage difference a problem? I figured since it's plugging into a standard outlet it shouldn't matter, but wanted to check.

Thanks

Comment: This is off topic as a shopping question.  However I’ll point you the right direction, order it from the [Broan Online Factory Parts Store](https://parts.broan-nutone.com/)

Comment: I disagree with this being off topic. The question could be reworded a bit to remove references to shopping, but the general question is just about the amperage. The correct answer is the one posted below, the higher amperage is from this being a more powerful fan, but everything is still low enough that you won't have any issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, the amperage does not matter.
What you've got there is a slightly more powerful fan.

A typical outlet is on a 15 or 20 amp circuit.  You can safely turn on devices adding up to 80% of the capacity.  Thus even with your fan running you've got 90% of the capacity of a 15 amp circuit left for other devices.